# E-signature/Digital signature for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, digital-signature

We wanted to have an e sign validation for Azure DevOps. We tried looking for plugins available in Azure Marketplace that can provide the functionality but couldnt find any.

Jira provides a number of functionalities for the same as mentioned below:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217404/digital-signature?hosting=server&tab=overview
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220599/vera-electronic-signatures-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview

Does anyone have inputs on integrating a digital signature solution with Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CFR – Code of Federal Regulations, Title 21, PART 11 ELECTRONIC RECORDS; ELECTRONIC SIGNATURES provides regulation through listing requirements needed for compliance. However, there is no specific guidance on the implementation to be complaint. Please check the blog below:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/e-signature-retirement-in-azure-devops-service-and-azure-devops-server/

If you do want this feature, please submit a User Voice at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21